# PyHook Keboard inputs are read incorrectly

Tags: python, pyhook

i was working on a project on python and it involves keyboard hooking with pyhook.I'm trying to get keyboard inputs.But unfortunately the inputs recieved is wrong somtimes.The following are the test code and the output i got from them.The problem occurs randomly but almost frequently.

**Test Code**

```
import pyHook, pythoncom


def OnKeyboardEvent(event):

    print(chr(event.Ascii))

    return True

hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager ( )
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard ( )
pythoncom.PumpMessages ()
```

**Output** :

[image]

and yeah that was abcd... i pressed. Any explanation and remedy for this problem is appreciated.

Comment: The site does accept and display arbitrary Unicode. Maybe you don't have the necessary fonts installed - then you'd see rectangles with codes instead of characters.

Comment: You can print `repr(event.Ascii)` - it is guaranteed to be printable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but that also prints weird characters :( .

Comment: Then it's not `print` that outputs them.

Comment: WFM if I delete excessive line breaks inside `OnKeyboardEvent` and `%paste` the code into `ipython` console.

Comment: The actual thing i'm doing is writing it to a file even that gives arbitrary unicodes.So i don't think it's a streaming problem.

Comment: If even with `repr` you get unreadable symbols then it's not `print` (and maybe not even your program) that produces them. Try hooking the KB without inputting anything.